# document.getElementById returns an object, which does not exist

Tags: javascript

I have a function, which is a part of some large code base, so, unfortunatelly, I can not provide a reproducible example. But still, let me ask this question. So, in this function I have such a code for debugging purposes:

```
 console.log(typeof document.getElementById("grid_object_89529_"));
 console.log(document.getElementById("grid_object_89529_"));
```

When I run my function once, I see this in the console:

[image]

Please, pay attention to this grey marker at the end of the second line. When I click on it, I can see where this element is located in the DOM.

When, however, I call my function for the second time, I see this:

[image]

And now, as you can see, this grey marker is missing and I can not inspect this component in the DOM as easily as in the first case. But if I inspect the DOM manually, I can find this element - it is not destroyed and it exists just in the same way as in the first case. So, what may be wrong with that? To prevent downvotes, let me ask a more practical question - is it possible to reproduce this situation with some arbitrary code?

Comment: I could ask it another way. Why in the second case I do not get null, if for some reason browser believes that this element does not exist? PS. I do not create this element with `createElement` or some other function. It is created with innerHTML.

Comment: BTW. If I add some large timeout, I can get the same result in the second run of my function. But this brings me now to another question, how can I check that some html element not only exists, but is rendered as well? It seems like checking for null is not enough.

Comment: Are you sure it's the exact *same* element that exists in the DOM, or only an element that looks equal to it?

Comment: On each function call, some DOM structure gets created and destroyed. The exact same innerHtml = '...'; happens. So, in true sense it is not the very same element. In my case it is a part of some window. When my window shows up, it creates some DOM. When I close it, it destroyes this DOM.

Comment: Yes. That means that *this particular object* does not exist in the document, and won't get the grey marker. It's a different node that you created - don't use `innerHTML`!

Comment: It is some legacy code, so I have to use it. But still, is it possible to check that some DOM element is completely rendered?

Comment: Sure, just use `document.getElementById("grid_object_89529_") != null` whenever you need to test. But don't log it and expect it to retain the reference.

Comment: But look, in my case, it is not null. This is what the second screen shows. It is not null, but it is not yet rendered.

Comment: It *was* not null. By the time that you look at the console, it is no longer rendered, but apparently an equal node exists in the DOM.

Comment: That is not the case. When I close the window and inspect the DOM, this element does not exist any more. So there is not any "equal node" by the time, when I open my window for the second time.

Comment: Yes, or that (though in your question you stated "*But if I inspect the DOM manually, I can find this element*"). In any case, the element that you *had logged* is no longer part of the dom, even when it *was* at the time of logging. Don't let the console confuse you.

Comment: Is there an actual problem with the application that is still concerning you?

Comment: Let me just describe all steps in sequence: 1) Open the window 2) Do innerHtml 3) run function and do console.log 4) Close the window and destroy all the relevant DOM 5) Open the window for the second time 6) Do innerHtml 7) run function again and do console.log again, So when you say that something is no longer part of the dom it is not quite right. I create new DOM structure once again at step 6

Comment: Yes, there is an actual problem. Some framework component is not rendered to this DOM element.

Comment: And what is the unexpected thing? That the element you logged in step 3 is no longer part of the dom after step 6? That step 7 does not log `null`?

Comment: The unexpected thing is that at step 7 (right after innerHtml), browser logs this element as if it is not yet rendered. It would be great, If I got null at this step - at least I could wait for this element, until it is not null.

Comment: So you assign `innerHTML`, you can find the element by id in the dom and log it, you can read back the `innerHTML` to confirm it exists - but you don't see the element being rendered on the screen, and the grey marker is missing in the console?

Comment: Exactly!..........

Comment: That would suggest something else is running after step 7, removing the elements. You can try to execute `findElementById` and reading `innerHTML` directly from the command line (instead of that function) when you don't see the element rendered, and it should yield according results.